# Excel linked IF statement loses cell range following macro update

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a basic macro within a workbook to clear data from a set number of tabs then copy in refreshed data from external workbooks. There is a master data tab within the workbook that uses IF formulas to obtain various stock information for that tab which then feeds through to other sheets. 
E.G.

```
=IF($A$2="","",SUMIF(Data_CoventryStock!$A:$A,Data!$A$2,Data_CoventryStock!$E:$E))
```

Currently when the macro runs it produces the desired result but the IF Formulas lose the reference to the range e.g. `$A:$A` becomes `#N/A!`

I've been looking online for a solution but am unable to see a suitable option. I am new to this area.

```
Sub Update()
'
' Update Macro
'
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' Clears data from tabs
    Sheets("Data_10Day").Select
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Sheets("Data_CoventryStock").Select
    Columns("A:E").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Sheets("Data_CowleyStock").Select
    Columns("A:E").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Sheets("Data_RugbyStock").Select
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Sheets("Data_10Day").Select

' Copies data from other workbooks then pastes

    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\ceasdown\Documents\HDS\Data\Data_10Day.xlsx"
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Coventry Ordering Template2.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Data_10Day").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Workbooks("Data_10Day.xlsx").Close



    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\ceasdown\Documents\HDS\Data\Data_CoventryStock.xlsx"
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Coventry Ordering Template2.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Data_CoventryStock").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
   Workbooks("Data_CoventryStock.xlsx").Close



   Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\ceasdown\Documents\HDS\Data\Data_CowleyStock.xlsx"
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Coventry Ordering Template2.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Data_CowleyStock").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
   Workbooks("Data_CowleyStock.xlsx").Close


    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\ceasdown\Documents\HDS\Data\Data_RugbyStock.xlsx"
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Coventry Ordering Template2.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Data_RugbyStock").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
   Workbooks("Data_RugbyStock.xlsx").Close

   Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I need it to retain the cell range in the IF formula so no manual update after running the macro is required.

Comment: This might help [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Do the entire columns need to be deleted? Or you can just clear the contents? The reference is probably lost because you are deleting the columns. Using `.ClearContents` instead of `.Delete` should do the trick.

Comment: you should also create a macro to re import the formula to the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your formulas get damaged is that you are *Deleting* the ranges they refer to.  Instead of deleting, use `ClearContents` instead.

Also, your code can do with quite a bit of optimsation.

Consider this

```
Sub Update()
    Dim wbMain As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim FilePath As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set wbMain = ActiveWorkbook

    With wbMain
        FilePath = Environ$("UserProfile") & "\Documents\HDS\Data\"
        ' Copies data from other workbooks then pastes
        UpdateFromWB .Worksheets("Data_10Day").Cells(1, 1), FilePath & "Data_10Day.xlsx", "WhatSheet?"
        UpdateFromWB .Worksheets("Data_CoventryStock").Cells(1, 1), FilePath & "Data_CoventryStock.xlsx", "WhatSheet?"
        UpdateFromWB .Worksheets("Data_CowleyStock").Cells(1, 1), FilePath & "Data_CowleyStock.xlsx", "WhatSheet?"
        UpdateFromWB .Worksheets("Data_RugbyStock").Cells(1, 1), FilePath & "Data_RugbyStock.xlsx", "WhatSheet?"

    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateFromWB(rngDest As Range, wbName As String, wsName As String)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=wbName)
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    With ws
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown), .Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight))
        'Alternative, in case there might be gaps in the data
        'Set rng = .Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    End With
    rngDest.Worksheet.Cells.ClearContents 'Delets ALL data from sheet.  Adjust range if required
    rngDest.Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
    wb.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. I've only been using VB for about 2 weeks so thanks for the useful tips. :)

Comment: @Clare thanks for the reply,  glad it helped.  FYI, SO protocol is to accept (click the tick) the answer that helped you most

Answer (score 0):

I try to create a code avoiding `.Select`, `.Activate` and repetition. The code is untested but it will give you an idea about the concept. For any question please ask me.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Update()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    '
    ' Update Macro
    '
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ' Clears data from tabs

        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook

            With ws

                If .Name = "Data_10Day" Or .Name = "Data_RugbyStock" Then
                    .Columns("A:B").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
                ElseIf .Name = "Data_CoventryStock" Or .Name = "Data_CowleyStock" Then
                    .Columns("A:E").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
                End If

            End With

        Next ws

        ' Copies data from other workbooks then pastes
        Call Procedure("Data_10Day.xlsx", "Data_10Day")
        Call Procedure("Data_CoventryStock.xlsx", "Data_CoventryStock")
        Call Procedure("Data_CowleyStock.xlsx", "Data_CowleyStock")
        Call Procedure("Data_RugbyStock.xlsx", "Data_RugbyStock.xlsx")

   Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

Sub Procedure(ByVal FileName As String, ByVal SheetName As String)

    Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\Users\ceasdown\Documents\HDS\Data\" & FileName

    Workbooks(FileName).Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy

    Workbooks("Coventry Ordering Template2.xlsm").Sheets(SheetName).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    Workbooks(FileName).Close

End Sub
```

Comment: `Call` is deprecated.